# Generate SQL script from excel sheet

Tags: sql, excel, xml

I'm trying to create a sql script from Excel sheet. This should insert the value of the cell's automatically. I have attempted as below, but this is not being excepted by Excel:

```
="INSERT INTO taSwitchFilter VALUES('"&A2&"','111','1','"&B3&"','"<properties actionContext="After"><rule type="SwitchRequestType"><switchRequestType type="List Event PGM" /></rule><rule type="Source"><source type="Logical"><logical name="&B3&" /></source></rule></properties>','69')"'
```

Can someone please help me correct this. I guess I'm close.

Answer (score 0):

The first error you have starts at the lesser than symbol **<** From this point onwards excel doesn't know what to do as it's no longer text

```
="INSERT INTO taSwitchFilter VALUES('"&A2&"','111','1','"&B3&"','"
```

Without being able to have a full conversation with you, making an educated guess my belief is that your formula should be this

```
="INSERT INTO taSwitchFilter VALUES('"&A2&"','111','1','"&B3&"','<properties actionContext=""After""><rule type=""SwitchRequestType""><switchRequestType type=""List Event PGM"" /></rule><rule type=""Source""><source type=""Logical""><logical name=" &B3& " /></source></rule></properties>','69')"
```

Note that if you want to include the quote character in the output, you actually need to put two quote characters Or Alternatively use & CHAR(34)& for the quote character.

The trick with these long formula is to break down the formula slowly rather than trying to do it in one go.
Good luck and hope it helps!